# NameError: global name 'Circulo_Mohr_v1_2' is not defined

Tags: python, pyqt4, nameerror

I'm trying make a simple menu (options: 1,2,3) and the second option (input 2) should run a graphical menu.

When I try run python reports a NameError (*"global name 'Circulo_Mohr_v1_2' is not defined"*).

I don't know the correct syntax

```
print "inicio"
import sys
from librerias import Circ_Mohr_motor_v2
import librerias.Circulo_Mohr_v1_2
from librerias import prueba_importacion

'''
def definicion_ventana():
    Circulo_Mohr_v3_0.Ui_CalculodecirculosMohr()

#Ui_CalculodecirculosMohr.setupUi()
'''
def seleccion_de_libreria():
    print '''Escoger opcion:
    1) motor
    2) Ventana
    3) test
    '''
    opcion = raw_input ("Opcion seleccionada: ")
    opcion = int (opcion)

    if opcion == 1:
        print "se ejecuta el motor de calculo"
        punto_Ax = raw_input ("Insertar coordenada X de primer punto: ")
        punto_Ay = raw_input ("Insertar coordenada Y de primer punto: ")
        punto_Bx = raw_input ("Insertar coordenada X de segundo punto: ")
        punto_By = raw_input ("Insertar coordenada Y de segundo punto: ")

        Circ_Mohr_motor_v2.circulo_mohr(punto_Ax,punto_Ay,punto_Bx,punto_By)
    elif opcion == 2:
        print "se ejecuta la funcion ventana"
        Circulo_Mohr_v1_2.Ui_CalculodecirculosMohr()
                print "fin la funcion ventana"
    else:
        print "se ejecuta el test"
        prueba_importacion.prueba_01()

seleccion_de_libreria()

print "fin"
```

How can I fix that?

Comment: maybe you can try replace `import librerias.Circulo_Mohr_v1_2` with  `from  librerias.Circulo_Mohr_v1_2 import Ui_CalculodecirculosMohr` and call directly `Ui_CalculodecirculosMohr()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try replace

```
import librerias.Circulo_Mohr_v1_2
```

with

```
from librerias.Circulo_Mohr_v1_2 import Ui_CalculodecirculosMohwith
```

and call directly Ui_CalculodecirculosMohr()

```
Ui_CalculodecirculosMohr()
```